# Why do I encounter Fatal error in publishing a Responsive Pricing Table?

Tags: wordpress

Once I hit publish in Add New pricing table I encounter this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sanitize_hex_color() in /var/domains/main/wp-content/plugins/dk-pricr-responsive-pricing-table/inc/rpt-save-metaboxes.php on line 69

Comment: its wordpress version issue. May I know what is the wordpress version you are using

Comment: I am using version 4.5.3

Answer (score 0):

in WordPress version 4.6, this function has been moved to the file wp-includes/formatting.php, first include this file, and then call the function :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sanitize_hex_color' ) ) {
        include ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/formatting.php';    
    }
```

Comment: You mean I will include formatting.php to rpt-save-metaboxes.php?

Comment: If you can upgrade to the latest version of WordPress, it's likely that your problem will be resolved